# VHDL - Vivado - Vivado Simulator retrieve old file instead of the newly generated one

Tags: file, vhdl, vivado

I am building a vhdl project within vivado 2020.2

My working directory is located at the local Desktop of my O.S. and it has the following structure:

```
script\
    datasets\
        gentestdata.py
        testdata\
            test_data.txt
src\
  <<source files here>>
tst\
  <<testbenches here>>
vivado\
  <<project directory here>>
```

I have the following impure function to load the data from a script-generated file test_data.txt :

```
impure function gen_datain(dataset_path: in string) return datain_type is

file text_header: text is in dataset_path;
variable text_line: line;
variable line_i: bit_vector(0 to neuron_rom_width-1);
variable dataset_content: datain_type;

begin
for i in dataset_content'range loop
    if i = 101 then
        readline(text_header, text_line);
        read(text_line, line_i);
    else
        readline(text_header, text_line);
        read(text_line, line_i);
    end if;
    dataset_content(i) := makesfixed(line_i);
end loop;
file_close(text_header);
return dataset_content;
end function;
```

The file test_data.txt is generated automatically by the Python script gentestdata.py. Every time I run this script the content of test_data.txt changes and so should the data which is loaded within the vivado environment, but somehow even if the old version of test_data.txt has been replaced by the newer one, the simulator still loads the old data. How can I fix this behaviour. I tried to close vivado and reboot the O.S.

My questions is, do you know the reason of such behavior, and how it can be corrected?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding files to the GUI project, Vivado allows the user to 'Copy file to project'; say no to the copy.  There is a check box or radio button involved.  Vivado will try to have its own local copy buried somewhere it its hierarchy. Vivado is free to remove and re-add its own folders and if your file is part of this it can become confusing.

You may need to start over with a fresh Gui project in order to have the project in a state where it is not modifying your files.

The ultimate solution is to use Vivado in non-project mode without the GUI.  This works better in a Linux based script driven environment than in Windows.  In non-project Vivado does not mess with your files.
See:
https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug892-vivado-design-flows-overview
For more on the trade-offs between project and non-project build work flows.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to prevent the simulator to load old input files to the testbench. Just for the records, I opened "Simulation settings" window, inside the "Project settings" section, I clicked on Simulation. Inside this window I entered the "Advanced" section and unchecked the box "Enable incremental compilation". After that, every time I would generate a new input file by using my scripts, the vivado simulator would load the new one instead of keeping on fetching the old ones.

Comment: Also, I definetely want to learn how to use non-project mode and how to write tcl commands to have full control over the design flow steps. It is definitely a skill I need to learn. Thank you for you advice, I have definitely benefited from them.